# Deep learning person detection with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, raspberry-pi3, tracking

so I'm really new here. Currently working on a public art project where I need a little help with the programming because I'm kind off lost between codes.

First I'll give you a short description of the goal of the work and then state my problem.

I'm putting a webcam in the shopwindow of a gallery that is facing out on a public street. This webcam is connected to a tv screen that is facing outwards on the street so people see themselves being filmed (like cctv). Then if people stand still long enough for the camera the webcam makes an automatic screenshot what will be emailed to a site which hold a script for automatic attachment printing and the people from the street instantly come in to my gallery, on paper.
(and yes I have permission from the gallery to do this since it is slightly in the grey area of legality)

I come from a art background with interest in programming so this was all very very new for me and made it already quite far I think. I have a raspberry pi running with open cv and put a script on it for deep learning object detection (https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/18/real-time-object-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv/) < the link I used for that.

I also come across loads of pedestrian tracking but did not find a suitable code yet for a real time video stream.

So what I need from you guys, is a little help with how to make a timer in the script so that when people stand still long enough for the camera, it wil make the screenshot. It is a bit like reversed security cams script because they react on movement and I want it to react to no movement at all.

The automatic attachment printing part I got covered I think because there are a lot of scripts already on the internet.

If you have any tips or tricks.. please let me know.

Help a girl out!

Marije

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of things you can try.

Is the camera faced towards a shopping street? In that case you could go for simple background subtraction. For each frame, apply some preprocessing (e.g. blurring, morpholoy operations), call `findContours` and compute the center of `minEnclosingRect` for each of these.

Another option is to use the inbuilt (and pretrained) HOG [`PeopleDetector`](http://mccormickml.com/2013/05/09/hog-person-detector-tutorial/). This is based on SVM (Support Vector Machines), which is another machine learning technique. For this to work efficiently you'd have to tune the parameters adequately. Since you're using a Pi you'd also need to consider the tradeoff between speed and accuracy. Using this technique, we'd be left with rectangles as well, so we can again compute the center.

For both techniques, you'd want to make sure that the center point doesn't fluctuate too much from frame to frame (that would mean the person is moving). For this you'd also want to take into account the framerate and understand that you can't guarantee person detection for every frame.

The caveat of the first technique, whilst having more explanatory power, would be that it'd detect ANYTHING that changes from frame to frame, that includes pets, bikes, cars (if on a public street) and so on. You could then consider filtering (e.g. by area, color).

Comment: Hai Jyr, Sorry for the super late response (holidays came in between) I'm going to look into the HOG today.. I could use your help though if you don't mind. I've come across this HOG before but didn't find a code for real time detection..

Comment: The answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34871294/full-body-detection-and-tracking-using-opencvpython-2-7) question should help.  Replace `'vid.avi'` with `0` to use the Pi webcam (I assume it's the module). Don't know what you're running on it, but might be that there's a command needed before you can use the webcam, I know that was the case when I used it with a Linux distro.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'm using a Logitech c170 usb webcam which I already had running on the Rpi. So then I could just use vid.avi right? The only thing I need then is to Import `time` in the same script right? I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36439902/auto-detect-face-and-take-a-snapshot-with-opencv) which I think would be a good starting point

Comment: No, replace `'vid.avi'` would direct to a prerecorded file on the Pi (which I doubt exist), you want real time, so you want to access the webcam stream, that is done by replacing `'vid.avi'` with `0` (or `1` or so on`2` or so on if you have multiple webcams. The link you posted has to do with face detection, which I don't think is a good fit here (e.g. people with backs turned).

Comment: I used the link you provided and made the change to 0, this is now the error I get: `OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0) in locateROI, file /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp, line 981
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peopledetect.py", line 25, in <module>
    found,w=hog.detectMultiScale(frame, winStride=(8,8), padding=(32,32), scale=1.05)
cv2.error: /home/pi/opencv-3.3.0/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp:981: error: (-215) dims <= 2 && step[0] > 0 in function locateROI`

Comment: It's saying the frame has less than 2 dimensions. Make sure you don't have the camera open anywhere else. I think your first hurdle is making sure you can read frames from your webcam. Since you're not using the Pi camera module extension itself, I can't tell you exactly what to do. [This](https://elinux.org/RPi_USB_Webcams) link says your webcam should be supported, so I'd recommend just trying out a tutorial that (mainly) has to do with setting up a webcam, e.g. [here](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/18/multiple-cameras-with-the-raspberry-pi-and-opencv/)

Comment: When I run the script my webcam sees it (the green 'on' light shows itself shortly) thanks for all of the help anyway, I'm still struggling to get it working..